# Call #ajax when a checkbox is checked or unchecked

Tags: 7, forms

I have a Drupal 7 form that I want to be a single checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, I want to call an ajax request that hits an API to update the value, same for when I uncheck it. However, this event is happening only once, unless I refresh the page.

Form code:

```
function mymodule_autorenew_form($form, &$form_state, $account, $renew_state, $order_id) {
  if (!isset($form_state['user'])) {
    $form_state['user'] = $account;
  }

  $form_state['order_id'] = $order_id;
  $renew_default = FALSE;

  if (in_array($renew_state, ['scheduled', 'complete'])) {
    $renew_default = TRUE;
  }

  $form['autorenew'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#description' => t('Enable auto-renewal'),
    '#ajax' => [
      'event' => 'change',
      'callback' => '_mymodule_autorenew_update',
      'progress' => 'none',
    ],
    '#default_value' => $renew_default,
  );

  return $form;
}
```

AJAX callback:

```
function _mymodule_autorenew_update($form, &$form_state) {
  $client = new ApiClient();
  $autorenew = (bool) $form_state['values']['autorenew'];
  $order_id = $form_state['order_id'];
  $response = $client->setAutoRenewState($autorenew, $order_id);
  cache_clear_all('mymodule_member:' . $form_state['user']->uid . ':membership', 'cache');
  return $form['autorenew'];
}
```

The first time you tick the box, the callback works and the data goes through the API. However subsequent clicks do nothing at all. What am I missing? $form_state['rebuild'] is already TRUE.

edit: No submit or submit button is desired. The end result should be a toggle checkbox without additional elements.

Comment: In D8 you have a choice either to define a wrapper or return an Ajax response. Shouldn't be any different in D7, but I don't recall what they've used instead of the Ajax response.

Comment: I initially returned an AJAX response of an alert() to just test this out, but it is indeed only fired one time. Subsequent clicks on the checkbox do not call the callback.

Comment: Welp, going back to commands fixes it, if I build a new form and insert that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been too long with 7 that I don't recall all the innerworkings of #ajax with forms, but I wound up just building a new form and returning that. Now it works every single time. Likely not the *best* approach but we just need this for a short term feature.

```
  $client->setAutoRenewState((bool) $form_state['values']['autorenew'], $form_state['order_id']);
  $new_form = drupal_get_form('mymodule_autorenew_form', $form_state['user'], $form_state['order_id']);
  $new_form = drupal_render($new_form);

  $commands = [];
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#autorenew-form', $new_form);
  return ['#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands];
```